# Common volume of three finite cylinders on a 2D plane

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, volume

Its quite a big question sorry... but I really am just looking for the starting point for three cylinders (not two sorry) on a 2D plane. Hopefully after that I can find the common volume for either unequal radii or at different angles like the photo below. Thank you for your help!

A shot in the dark of what I have so far.. (not too sure if it is of use)
Cylinder equations
$$x^2 + y^2 = r_1^2$$
$$x^2 + z^2 = r_2^2$$
$$y^2 + z^2 = r_3^2$$        where $r_1 \neq r_2 \neq r_3$

The common volume for infinite cylinders with equal radii using triple integration with circular co-ordinates is:
$$V_c = 8\cdot(2-\sqrt 2)\cdot r^3$$

(following [this great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vA9uhl7dAbg))

[image: 3 cylinders]
[image: birds eye]

Comment: The picture suggests that you want the volume where $x,y,z\geq0$.  Is this the case?

Comment: Even for two cylindres this problem seems to be a nightmare.

Comment: Yes please or the picture shows best of what I want to do. Sorry if my maths is quite poor! Thank you!

Comment: For two cylinders in the finite case, I can divide the infinite cylinder common volume case by 4 to get the finite case I think. I followed this paper reference to get the two cylinder case:  ElMaraghy, W., Valluri, S., Skubnik, B. and Surry, P. (1994). Intersection volumes and surface areas of cylinders for geometrical modelling and tolerancing. Computer-Aided Design, 26(1), pp.29-45.

Comment: What is the radius of the smallest cylinder? What are the equations of the axes of the cylinders? Or do you want solve the problem in general?

Comment: the general solution please